# Can't use get parameter

Tags: php, get, url-rewriting

1. My .htaccess: `Rewriterule ^(.*?)-(?:.*).html$ ver.php?id=$1 [L]`
2. My URL is like this: http://www.site.com/listado/s.html
3. I can't use `GET` to parse pages: `ie: http://www.site.com/listado/s.html?page=2

What am I doing wrong?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the `QSA` flag, so mod_rewrite will append your query string to the rewrite.

```
Rewriterule ^(.*?)-(?:.*).html$ ver.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```